# Skip empty row in CSV file using Java

Tags: java, csv

I am using the Scanner method to read the csv file in Java. And wish to skip the empty row in the output.
What method should I use?

```
Scanner s=new Scanner(new File("file location"));
s.useDelimiter(",");

while(s.hasNext()){
 System.out.print(s.next());    
 System.out.print("|");
  System.out.print("\t");
 }
s.close();
```

Comment: use this code to solve your problem String line = "";
while (s.hasNext()) {
    if (!(line = s.nextLine()).isEmpty()) {
         System.out.print(line);
         System.out.print("|");
         System.out.print("\t");
    }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a row is empty it will contain (col - 1) delimiters in that line of the file.

For example, with 5 columns, an empty row would be line 2, with (5-1)=4 delimiters:

```
line1: 5,4,3,2,1
line2: ,,,,
line3: 1,2,3,4,5
```

So scan in each line, split by delimiter, and ignore unless the length of the line is greater than number of columns - 1.

```
Scanner s=new Scanner(new File("file location"));

while(s.hasNextLine()){
    String line = s.nextLine();
    String[] cols = line.split(",");

    // if every col is empty, the line will equal col-1 delimiters.
    if(line.length() > cols.length - 1){ 
        for(String str : cols){
            System.out.print(str);    
            System.out.print("|");
            System.out.print("\t");
        }
    }
}
s.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could go through file lines by [nextLine](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29) (and his **has*** part), check for [emptiness](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty%28%29) and [split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) the string by your delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to print `length` for `s.next()` you can figure out what is causing this. It is caused of end of line characters `\r` and `\n`. So, removing them will give the desired result.

```
Scanner s=new Scanner(new File("1.csv"));
s.useDelimiter(",");
String contentRead="";
while(s.hasNext()){
   contentRead = s.next().replaceAll("\\r","");
   contentRead = contentRead.replaceAll("\\n","");
   if(!contentRead.isEmpty()){
      System.out.print(contentRead);    
      System.out.print("|");
      System.out.print("\t");
   }
}
s.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to solve your problem and skip empty line while reading CSV using Scanner

```
String line = "";
while (s.hasNext()) {
    if (!(line = s.nextLine()).isEmpty()) {
         System.out.print(line);
         System.out.print("|");
         System.out.print("\t");
    }
}
```

Comment: that won't work, an empty row in a csv isn't an empty line, it's a series of delimiters with nothing between them.

Answer (score 0):

There is no method available in Scanner class to achieve this.

here, rather than using "," as delimiter, use "\n" as delimiter.
This will help you get a particular line contents in each iteration.

Then you can verify if content of that particular line suit you and proceed as required.

```
s.useDelimiter("\n");

while(s.hasNext())
{
   line = s.next();
   System.out.println("\nNext Line :" +line);

   //Here, tokenize the line and verify if any non-empty token exists

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

CSV can be tricky:

- **individual values may contain a newline separator (e.g. v1, "v2[\n]and a new line", v3):** if you use a nextLine() equivalent you won't parse the data correctly.
- **individual values may contain the delimiter (e.g. v1,"v2[,] and more stuff", v3):** in this case simply relying on a split() equivalent will produce multiple values instead of one.
- **Line breaks won't be handled properly in multiple platforms (e.g. v1 "v2[\r\n]and a new line", v3):** if you parse this in Linux or MACOS the second column will be parsed to produce a blank line between **v2** and **and a new line** (i.e. you'll get 3 lines instead 2).

Use a the CSV parser that comes with [uniVocity-parsers](http://www.univocity.com/pages/parsers-tutorial) to handle these sorts of situations reliably:

```
CsvParserSettings settings = new CsvParserSettings(); // many options here, check the tutorial.
settings.getFormat().setLineSeparator("\r\n");

CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(settings);
List<String[]> allRows = parser.parseAll(new FileReader(new File("path/to/file.csv")));
```

Disclosure: I am the author of this library. It's open-source and free (Apache V2.0 license).